# Getting weird error when trying to install packages in Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, debian, apt, debian-jessie

I am running apt-get install in a Dockerfile (base image Debian:Jessie) and getting the error :

```
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/tmp.2aQvTy9NOu': No such file or directory
```

I am not sure what this means or what I should try.

Comment: It is hard to help you without having more information. Can we see the Dockerfile that you are using? Can we also see also the previous lines of the output before that error?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]